# how to create a MDX query to count customer retention

Tags: ssas, mdx, cubes

How can I get the retained customer from the previous year?
**1. Customer Retention...the most recent trailing 12 months vs the previous 12 months...exclude new business...what % of customers are we still selling to? Ideally 100%...**

> explaining the above statement:-

I need the percentage of customers who were retained this year from the previous year depending on sales. for example- 1,2,3,4,5 (This year) are the customers doing business with us this year and 1,2,3,4,6 (previous Year) are the customers doing business in the previous year. so what I am looking for is the number of customers who have been retained from the previous year is 1,2,3,4 is (Four) divided by the total number of customers whom we are doing business within the previous year 1,2,3,4,6 is (Five). If I can get this somehow the percentage calculation is simple. So the percentage of customers who have been retained is (4/5)*100 = 80%. I want to calculate this as a measure for all the years.

Comment: please supply the `MDX` you have already attempted - folks on SO expect questioners to make an attempt and supply that attempt